# Laravel relationship HasMany

Tags: php, laravel

I keep multiple address records belonging to a user. but when i write with dd i can't access other table's data.

Following my code:

`user` Table

```
id |    name       | country |
--- --------------  ----------   

7  | Mr. Lenny Bins| Belgium
2  | Dalton Miller | Swaziland
```

`address` Table

```
user_id | address         
-------- ---------
7       | 740 Brown Greens Suite  
7       | 9906 Cleora Wall Apt.      
2       | 53977 Kip Center Apt
```

`UserModel`

```
 public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
    }
```

`UserController`

```
$users = User::where('id' ,7)->with('getAddress')->get();

dd($users->toArray());
// The output of this is below
```

[image: The output of this]

`dd($users->getAddress->toArray());`

I get an error when I try like this.

Property [getAddress] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are using get that will return collection, In Following you will get all users with their addresses.

`$users = User::where('id' ,7)->with('getAddress')->get();`

You can use `first()` instead of `get()` as you are finding only one user

```
$user = User::where('id' ,7)->with('getAddress')->first();
```

If You want only address of that user use

```
dd($user->getAddress)
```

Or If you want only in form of array use

```
dd($user->getAddress->toArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

User Model

```
public function getAddress()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
}
```

Get User(s)

```
$users = \App\User::with('getAddress')->where('id' ,7)->get();
```

Iterate and read data

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
  echo '<pre>' , var_dump($user->getAddress()->first()['address']) , '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$users = User::with('getAddress')->where('id' ,7)->first();

dd($users);

Comment: I understand, but how can I pull only addresses?

Comment: Well you are pulling users not addresses so you have user with the relation getAddress. You could use a select getAddress.* or just query address whereHas user with Id 7